# Why Array Value Shows Undefined Offset?

Tags: php, arrays

Does not parse_url() extract all the properties of the URL and dump each property in an array?
By properties I mean:
scheme
host
port
user
pass
path
query
fragment

So the array looks like this, I reckon:

```
["0"=>"scheme","1"=>"host","2"=>"port","3"=>"user","4"=>"pass","5"=>"path","6"->"query","7"=>"fragment"]
```

So now, I adding all this array to $url_properties = array();
And trying to echo each value of the array. Like so ...

```
<?php

$url = 'http://user:password@domain.com/path.php?query_string=value#fragment1';

print_r(parse_url($url)); echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
var_dump(parse_url($url)); echo '<br>';

$url_properties = array();
$url_properties = parse_url($url);

echo $url_properties[0];
echo $url_properties[1];
echo $url_properties[2];
echo $url_properties[3];
echo $url_properties[4];
echo $url_properties[5];
echo $url_properties[6];
echo $url_properties[7];

?>
```

But I get an error:
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 12
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 13
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 14
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 15
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 16
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 17
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 18
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 19

Why is that?

This however works ....

```
<?php

$url = 'http://user:password@domain.com/path.php?query_string=value#fragment1';

print_r(parse_url($url)); echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
var_dump(parse_url($url)); echo '<br>';

$url_properties = array();
$url_properties = parse_url($url);

foreach($url_properties AS $property)
{
    echo $property;
}

?>
```

I get echoed:
**httpdomain.comuserpassword/path.phpquery_string=valuefragment1**

This is proof that the $url_properties array is not empty.
So why the error on my first code when trying to echo each of the values of this array? Strange!

EDIT:
I have realised my error. The array is an associative array and so this is working:

```
echo $url_properties['scheme'];
echo $url_properties['user'];
echo $url_properties['pass'];
echo $url_properties['host'];
echo $url_properties['port'];
echo $url_properties['path'];
echo $url_properties['query'];
echo $url_properties['fragment'];
```

But what few lines of code should I add so that even the following works and does not give undefined offset errors?

```
echo $url_properties[0];
echo $url_properties[1];
echo $url_properties[2];
echo $url_properties[3];
echo $url_properties[4];
echo $url_properties[5];
echo $url_properties[6];
echo $url_properties[7];
```

Comment: `$url_properties = array_values($url_properties);`, use array_values for 
converting associative array to indexed array

Comment: @Tushar, Thanks but how to echo each value. I don't want to print_r() or var_dump(). Just plain echo. Can you show me a code sample ? Cheers!

Comment: Answered and added

Comment: @NutCrackingDude did you see my answer? that solve your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For converting associative array to indexed array, use `array_values`:

```
$url_properties = array_values($url_properties);

echo $url_properties[0];
echo $url_properties[1];
echo $url_properties[2];
echo $url_properties[3];
echo $url_properties[4];
echo $url_properties[5];
echo $url_properties[6];
echo $url_properties[7];
```

Comment: I just experimented and wrote exactly like your's. Now I see you wrote exactly like me before I wrote it. Your answer is now confirmation that my experimenting code is accurate and I do not have to add another EDIT on my question to ask about my experimenting code. I gave your answer a TICK. Thanks!

Comment: I have accepted your answer aswell.

Comment: @NutCrackingDude but you accept another anwer

Comment: I forgot to accept your answer the other day and so accepted it now. Check.

Comment: I gave points to both Tushar and your answer but accepted your answer because you answered first. Check. You will see, I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Answering as per comment by OP,

For converting associative array to indexed array, use array_values, like

```
$url_properties = array_values($url_properties);
```

Then add a `foreach` loop to print each value

```
foreach ($url_properties as $item)  {
            echo $item ."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted your answer aswell.